# mediaelement.js android (chrome), fullscreen button misplaced

Tags: android, google-chrome, mediaelement.js

I'm using MediaElement.js to make a responsive web application.
However, I have some issues to make it work on Android Chrome browser (I have a Samsung Galaxy S3).
When I try to open a video, the fullscreen button is misplaced: probably the "toolbar" elements are too big, and the last button (i.e. fullscreen) get placed in the next line.
It happens even in fullscreen mode: the fullscreen button disappears.

The same behaviour can be seen in the demo video on mediaelement.js website too.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the site on Chrome for Android's DevTools the button has an off by one error.

To learn more on how to do this yourself: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging

If you open devtools, you can alter the video scrubber (The bar in the middle) and reduce the size by a pixel and it's fixed.

I'd raise a bug with MediaElement.js - if their CSS is 100% correct then it may be a Chrome specific bug in which case a bug should be raised at crbug.com